# Getting the error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError error while launching the headless browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

While launching the headless browser using **Phantomjs**, getting the below exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.find(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.findPhantomJS(PhantomJSDriverService.java:232)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.createDefaultService(PhantomJSDriverService.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:94)
```

**OS is Mac**

Config for launching headless browser is

```
File src = new File("src/test/resources/phantomjs_mac");
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", src.getAbsolutePath());
driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
```

Updated the complete trace

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod LaunchBrowser
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.find(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.findPhantomJS(PhantomJSDriverService.java:232)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.createDefaultService(PhantomJSDriverService.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:94)
    at baseHelper.BrowserLauncher.LaunchBrowser(BrowserLauncher.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:514)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:589)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:113)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:206)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:177)
```

Comment: Can you consider updating us about the platform where you are trying to use `Phantomjs`. Once you initialize `Phantomjs driver` try to navigate to an url. Incase you see any error consider providing the full stacktrace for further analysis. Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB Os is mac. As i want to use for headless browser, i'm considering phantomjs. i'm getting this error while assigning phantomjs driver to webdriver variable. To navigate to URL, driver variable should have a value but null is being assigned to phantomjs driver. if i user firefox driver, tests run smoothly.

Comment: Could you please verify that the file (src) exists?

Comment: @Eugene yes the file exists

Comment: Could you please try to print the path to ensure that this path to the directory?

Comment: @Eugene `path ==> src/test/resources/phantomjs_mac` and 
`pathGetAbsolutePath ==> /Users/nagarjunareddy/Documents/projectworkspace/eclipse/AutoPost/src/test/resources/phantomjs_mac`
Getting the right path

Comment: Is phantomjs_mac is directory or binary?

Comment: @Eugene that's binary file

Comment: So this was my suspicion, could you please set in the property a path to the directory instead to the file?

Comment: @Eugene no luck. Still same error

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

When we use Phantomjs we have to provide the **absolute path** of the Phantomjs executable. Remember to specify the `WebDriver` Class before specifying the **Implementation** `new PhantomJSDriver();`

Here is the example in Windows:

```
 File path=new File("C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");
 System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path",path.getAbsolutePath());
 WebDriver driver= new PhantomJSDriver();
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
 driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.co.in/");
```

PS: Kindly convert it into Mac recognizable format.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: no, `WebDriver driver= new PhantomJSDriver();` this is giving null value to driver

Comment: it's already converted `File src = new File("src/test/resources/phantomjs_mac");` and i have kep it in the project directory

Comment: Can you consider updating the current code block and full error stacktrace please? Thanks

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy It isn't mandatory to keep it in Project directory, you can keep it anywhere on your system but provide the absolute path. Thanks

Comment: As it will be convinient, i have kept the driver inside the project. Updated the full stack trace in the question

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy Can you consider showing us your `BeforeMethod LaunchBrowser`? Thanks

Comment: [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4SgyzyvwKhia0t3aHN4b3BtNmc) please find it here

Answer (score 0):

System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", src.getAbsolutePath()) does not work in case of PhanotmJS
However, you can setup the DesiredCapabilities and pass it to the PhantomJSDriver.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, System.getProperty("user.dir") + /drivers/phantomjs.exe");

WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.co.in/");
driver.get("http://google.com");
```

Make sure your pom file does not use selenium version 3.6.0. Instead, use below dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(); will always result in an error so you cannot use an empty constructor.

I hope that helps.